# Maximum of 63 bits in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, integer, bit-manipulation

I'm building a system where I need to assign users access to a specific (individual) number of assets. These assets (potentially numbering  in the tens of thousands).

I thought to do it with bitwise comparisons, so something like storing the value of 3 if a user has access to assets 1 and 2, a value of 7 for access to 1, 2 and 3, etc. etc.

The access is not necessarily sequential, so a user could easily have access to assets 10, 12 and 24324.

I quickly ran into a problem using bits where the server wouldn't pick up assets beyond the 63rd bit, so obviously I've either misunderstood something, or bits is a dumb way to store this kind of info.

My code, running on a 64-bit Linux system, is this (just for testing purposes obviously, to discover just such limitations as this):

```
<?php

$bitwise = $_GET['bitwise'];

if (isset($bitwise)) {

    echo "<br/>bitwise input: ";
    echo $bitwise;
    $bitcount = 0;
    for ($i=1;$i<=$bitwise;$i*=2) {

        if (($i & $bitwise) > 0) {

            $bitcount++;
            echo "<br/>{$bitcount}: " . $i . " is in " . $bitwise;

        }

    }

}
```

?>

And I input test values via the querystring. However, no matter what value I input, the maximum count I can get to is 63.

So, my question is: Is this simply because I'm using bitwise comparisons for something they're not ideal for (my theory), or is my implementation of it just wrong?

My next go-to solution would be to store the "bits" in arrays, so if someone has access to assets 1, 2 and 3 I'll store their list as [1,2,3]. It's unlikely that someone has access to more than, say, a hundred specific assets. Is this a reasonable way to do it? I realize this puts the question somewhat into discussion-worthy territory, but hopefully it's still specific enough.

Paramount concerns are, of course, performance if the server has to serve a large number of clients at the same time.

(please excuse wrong terminology where applicable, hopefully my meaning is clear).

Comment: So what do you expect? On a 64bit system the boundaries of an integer are `+/- 9.22e+18 = 2^63`

Comment: You are correct; integers are limited to 64 bits. This is quite a lot, but it does mean in your case that you won't get farther this way. I would suggest using your alternative using an array.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11783079/can-bitwise-math-be-used-for-one-to-many-relationships-in-sql

Comment: Why don't you use a common (and normalized) solution that involves assigning a user his/her unique ID, and associating that ID with certain assets (store each ID and asset pair as a separate row in a database, for example)?

Comment: @RainFromHeaven I think I like your idea, I'm just worried it might be a hassle to keep updated unless I find a way to reliable determine what was changed, without relying on the client to tell me.

Comment: @MikkelFausing, RainFromHeaven's solution should be no more of a hassle than your (incorrect) bitwise integer solution. If you have to make changes to the table, you would have had to manipulate the bitwise value. Also, the solution of storing pairs in a second table seems to be the same as your idea of storing an array (except the array is how you access it in PHP, the table is how you persist it)

Comment: I'd just like to retract my previous statement, @RainFromHeaven and others: access pairs is definitely the way to go. Add a little INNER JOIN  and it's all good.

Comment: No join necessary, `SELECT asset_id FROM table_with_asset_and_user_id_pairs WHERE user_id = ?` ought to get the job done. Database normalization FTW.

Comment: Of course, to just get the access pairs, I don't need the join, it's only once I start doing something with that data. Thanks for steering me in the right direction though, as the array-idea would just be more difficult in the long run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is standard behavior — on 64 bit compiled PHP, integers have a maximum length of 64 bits.  While it warms my secret grey beard heart, if you have more than 64 different roles, a bitwise solution is the wrong one for access control.

Two other things worth mentioning.

First, doing this for performance reasons is probably a premature optimization for a web application.  ACL lookups aren't going to be the bottleneck in your system for a long time, if at all.  Also, it's not clear if bitwise operators offer that much PHP performance benefit, given the language's dynamically typed nature.

Second, the reason you're limited to 63 bits is because PHP (appears to?) use [Two's compliment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) for their implementation of signed integers. The final bit is for representing positive or negative numbers. I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18754198/confusing-php-bitwise-not-behavior) about the bitwise `NOT` a while back, which is why this question caught my eye.